# Spring Auto-wiring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Assuming i have two classes Circle and Rectangle that implement an interface called Shape.
And i have the following class:

```
public class ObjectFactory {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("circle")
    Shape shape;
.......
.......
.......
}
```

What i want to do is to remove the @Qualifier and make the autowiring depend on  some condition (for example if condition is true then inject Circle, if the condition is false, inject the rectangle) or make the wiring depend on a naming convention.
Is there a way to do that ?

Let me explain, If i remove the @Qualifier annotation, i'm going to end up with the following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No unique bean of type [com.app.objects.Shape] is defined: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: [circle, rectangle]
```

Is there a way to handle programmatically that exception in order to have a condition dependent auto-wiring ?

Comment: Where would you want to specify these conditions?

Comment: @skaffman : i want them to be specified in a separate class that will handle all the auto-wiring conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) in `@Resource`, perhaps you can use it in `@Qualifier` as well.

But normally such logic can be placed in a `FactoryBean`, where you can decide which instance to return.